# How to optimize a slow running query with multiple 'AND' statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to cleanup old records from a DB (SQL Server) which has only 1 table with millions of records in it & the query I'm using takes forever to run. Is it possible to optimize this one?

```
DECLARE @Count INT = -15;
DECLARE @CountThreshold INT = -4;
DECLARE @DeletedRows INT = 0 WHILE @Count <= @CountThreshold BEGIN BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
DELETE [Log]
WHERE [Date] <= DATEADD(d, @Count, getdate())
  AND (windowsIdentity LIKE 'BTA-SL%'
       AND Environment ='')
  SET @Count = @Count + 1;



PRINT 'DELETED '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DeletedRows) + ' ROWS ON COUNT - '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Count)
COMMIT TRANSACTION T1 END
```

Comment: Short answer: No, assuming you need those conditions. Long answer: decide between being okay with a long running query because you don't run it often and better structuring your DB. For example, use different tables for each windowsIdentity or environment.

Comment: Which percentage of rows is going to be deleted with first run (<= dateadd -15)? Do you have any indexes on this table? Isn't your transaction blocked by any other process?

Comment: This DB is on Windows Azure. Indexing have been set to run automatically. This query runs daily from an scheduled task so it'll cleanup records from 1 day. In case schedule task failed to run for few days the number -15 was set for '@Count'. Basically what i need to do is to delete any record which is older than 4 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while is not util because @CountThreshold  < @Count. your can do simply this:

```
  DECLARE @CountThreshold INT = -4;

  DELETE [Log]
  WHERE [Date] <=DATEADD(d, @CountThreshold , getdate())
   AND (windowsIdentity LIKE 'BTA-SL%'
   AND Environment ='');

  PRINT 'DELETED '+  CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' rows deleted'

  COMMIT TRANSACTION T1 END
```